# What are advantages and disadvantages of bernoulli assignment/randomization?

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, treatment-effect, random-allocation

This is good explanation for what is Bernoulli assignment is.
[For treatment assignment, what is the difference between Bernoulli assignment vs. completely randomized assignment?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300453/for-treatment-assignment-what-is-the-difference-between-bernoulli-assignment-vs)

I am wondering, what are benefits and drawbacks of using Bernoulli assignment? What are the scenarios that this method is desired?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of this simple randomization procedure is that it is easy to
implement. You just use a coin or a computer and allocate treatment option for each patient basing on Head or Tail. However, the major disadvantage is that, although in the long run the number of participants in each group will be in the proportion anticipated, there could be unbalanced between two arms. In addition, although with very very small probability, this randomization scheme might end up with unwanted outcome, that is all 1 (or all 0) appear. In this case, you cannot compare two treatments.

Comment: Random assignment is as easy to implement: draw names from a hat, or use a computer. You do need to know how many patients you'll have beforehand though; which is not the case with Bernoulli assignment - just assign each to an arm when he/she walks through the door of the clinic, & carry on for the duration of the trial.